# Stop music after resume using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: java, android

I'm working in an app for android. I'm streamming online radios. I'm facing this issue related to my app. I displayed a notification message, when the user click on it, it should reopen the last activity. To bring in front the last activity I set the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` option. This works ok. The problem is with the music, because when the activity is brought to the front it stopped. I've already set `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onCreate` method.

I tried not using any flag and it works good, but I'm creating many activities in the process: one per each time the notification is clicked.

I also checked that I'm not setting the `pause/stop` of my mediaplayer.

**Edit**

This is solved. See my answer.

Comment: Could you explain why media playback is stopping when switching activities? Are you hosting the media playback logic within the activity? If so, I would advise to refrain from doing so and moving it to a service.

Comment: I have it on a service. But I guess it could be because my cellphone is too slow and stop playing. Happens before tho.

Answer (score 0):

I removed any flag in my notification intent, which result in undesirable behavior when I hit back button. So, I need to override `onBackPressed` and calling myself my activity.